# linecache19 wont install via bundler

Tags: rubygems, bundler

Im trying to install the gem linecache19 via bundler and it always returns:

```
Installing linecache19 (0.5.12) /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:388:in `ensure_required_ruby_version_met': linecache19 requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2. (Gem::InstallError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:156:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:279:in `preserve_paths'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/bin/bundle:13
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

Obviously it looks like i have the wrong version of ruby installed but I know for a fact I have ruby 1.9.2 installed:

```
me@host:/rails/gitlabhq$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

I tried manually installing the gem which worked no problem, but bundler still returns that output and refuses to move on.

```
me@host:/rails/gitlabhq$ sudo gem install linecache19
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed linecache19-0.5.12
1 gem installed
```

I'm not sure why bundler is not installing the gem/not seeing it in the system gem library.

I dont have RVM or anything like that installed on this server, it just uses the system ruby and system gem library.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting your bundle via `rm -rf vendor/bundle`

Answer (score -1):

This [pull request](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/144) makes me think it will work if you bundle with this option

```
bundle install --without development test
```

YMMV